# How to extend HERE map library?

Tags: android, design-patterns, plugins, extensibility, here-api

I am wondering if HERE map library for android is designed to be extensible with plugins or a way to overloaded exiting classes to add new user's features... specially on the drawing parts.

Answer (score 1):

In general extending of SDK Library is not possible. But you can create your own namespace with own classes in which you can implement listeners which achieve the functionality.